# MATLABにおいてデータから散布図をプロットする方法について

Tags: matlab

MATLABで以下のように散布図を作成しようとしています。
以下のグラフはexcelで作成しました。
[image: 作成したい散布図のイメージ]

[MATLABドキュメンテーション](https://jp.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html)を読みましたが、データから散布図をプロットするスクリプトについては書かれておらず、どのように修正すればいいか見当がつかないです。
ラインプロットはできています。

MATLAB バージョン　：R2019a

エラーメッセージ

```
>> sample
Error using scatter (line 46)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in untitled (line 8)
scatter(data,'filled')
```

実行スクリプト

```
data = [11,10;10,11;9,10;20,18;10,11;11,10;10,9];

figure;
plot(data)


figure;
scatter(data,'filled')
```

ご回答に対して追記
[image: 回答２で作成されたplot]
時系列やラベルごとにおける（今回の場合1~7）２つの系列を確認したい場合、回答１の方法で描くという理解で正しいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これでどうでしょうか？二つ目のものを普通「散布図」と呼びます。

```
data = [11,10;10,11;9,10;20,18;10,11;11,10;10,9];

figure;
plot(data,'.')

figure;
scatter(data(:,1), data(:,2), 'filled')
```

なおエラー"Not enough input arguments."の意味ですが、scatterという関数は2つのベクトルを因数にとりますが、一つの行列dataしか与えていないことが原因で出ています。上記と同じ内容ですが、

```
v1 = [11 10 9 20 10 11 10];
v2=[10 11 10 18 11 10 9];
scatter(v1, v2)
```

でも散布図がでます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。２つ目のものが「散布図」であるなら、今回質問で掲載させていただき、回答１でplot(data,'.')で示していただいたグラフはなんと呼ぶのでしょうか。

Comment: 1番目の回答でよいです。あるいは下記のように明示的にx軸方向の値をplot()に与える方法もあります。
`data = [11,10;10,11;9,10;20,18;10,11;11,10;10,9];
xaxis = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
figure;
plot(xaxis,data(:,1),'o')
hold on
plot(xaxis,data(:,2),'o')`
掲載されている図に関して、特別このようなプロットの仕方を呼ぶ名前はないのではないかと思います。「系列のプロット」とかでしょうか。